# how to remove date from tweets?

Tags: python, regex

Need some advice with this...I have some collection of tweets

```
Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT @switchfoot http://twitpic.com/2y1zl - Awww, that's a bummer. :( You shoulda got David Carr of Third Day to do it. ;D
Mon Apr 06 22:19:49 PDT is upset that he can't update his Facebook by texting it... and might cry as a result :( School today also. Blah!
Mon Apr 06 22:19:53 PDT @Kenichan I dived many times for the ball. Managed to save 50% :( The rest go out of bounds
Mon Apr 06 22:19:57 PDT my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire :(
```

How I can remove this Mon Apr 06 22:19:57 PDT? using regex?

Comment: What produces that output? Can't you change that at all?

Comment: I have tried regex re.sub but results was unsatisfied...

Comment: To Martijn,  the output has to same tweets but without date and this PDT thing...actually all tweets are same ...having same form of date with PDT...What that PDT actually means after all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a string, simply split the line on the first `PDT`:

```
for line in tweets.splitlines():
    print line.split(' PDT ', 1)[1]
```

The line is split on the first occurrence of the characters `PDT` (with spaces), and the second half of the result is printed.

But perhaps you can instead prevent the code that outputs the string from adding in the date in the first place?

Comment: @katrielalex: sure, but there is no information about what variance there is in the timestamps *at all*.

Comment: Oh, true, true. But I think it's safer to assume that the times will always be formatted the same than to assume they'll always be in the same timezone.

Comment: Thx it's really worked for me))) I am newbie and didnt get in it can u explain why u used split for that?

Comment: @Aikin: With a fixed format where there is *always* an easily recognized set of characters delimiting the parts, `.split()` is the easiest and most easily understood method.

Answer (score 2):

```
for line in lines:
    print line[24:]
```

might be simple if the date/time format is always the same.

Comment: Unless you can change the tweet format, I think this is the best way -- it relies only on the twitter output format not changing.

Answer (score 1):

If they are strings all stored in the same way you could just do a split:

```
tweet = "Mon Apr 06 22:19:57 PDT SomeGuy Im not white enough to be excited for a new version of Windows".

tweet= tweet.split(None, 5)[-1]
```

Results in tweet being

> "SomeGuy Im not white enough to be excited for a new version of
>   Windows"

Comment: Much more concise. I didn't know Split could do that. Now I do. Documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0):

Seems like splitting it into a list of words and lopping off the first six is more likely to stay consistent across timezone changes.

```
clean_tweets = []

for tweet in tweets:
    words = tweet.split()
    del words[0:5]
    clean_tweet = " ".join(words)
    clean_tweets.append(clean_tweet)
```

By default, [split()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will split on spaces, so you don't have to specify the divider.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can't use PDT, because you can't assume they'll always be PDT.  Seems like the most easily identifiable part in the string is [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ - the time.

```
/^.*[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s+[A-Z]{3}\s*(.*)$/
```

captures the string after the time and a 3 letter time zone in all caps.

Answer (score 0):

I create a generalized pattern in case the date and timezone change

```
 data="""Mon Apr 06 22:19:45 PDT @switchfoot http://twitpic.com/2y1zl - Awww, 
 that's a bummer. :( You shoulda got David Carr of Third Day to do it. ;D
 Mon Apr 06 22:19:49 PDT is upset that he can't update his Facebook by texting 
 it... and might cry as a result :( School today also. Blah!
 Mon Apr 06 22:19:53 PDT @Kenichan I dived many times for the ball. Managed to 
 save 50% :( The rest go out of bounds
 Mon Apr 06 22:19:57 PDT my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire :("""

for line in data.splitlines():
    pattern=r'[a-zA-Z]{3}\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\s\d{2}\s(\d{2}\:*){3}\s[a-zA-Z]{3}'
    line=re.sub(pattern,'',line)
    print("{}\n".format(line))
```

output:

```
@switchfoot http://twitpic.com/2y1zl - Awww, that's a bummer. :( You shoulda got David Carr of Third Day to do it. ;D

 is upset that he can't update his Facebook by texting it... and might cry as a result :( School today also. Blah!

 @Kenichan I dived many times for the ball. Managed to save 50% :( The rest go out of bounds my whole body feels itchy and like its on fire :(
```